# How to get all scheduled changes for a product in Magento commerce?

Tags: magento2, magento-2-commerce, content-staging

I have added 2 schedules to a product in Magento as shown below.

[image]

Below code gives list of all schedules present in our database but there is no sku/product_id relation here.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\CustomImport\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria;

class Test
{
  
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    protected $updateRepository;

    public function __construct
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        \Magento\Staging\Api\UpdateRepositoryInterface $updateRepository
    ) {
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->updateRepository = $updateRepository;
    }

    public function getSchedule()
    {
    try {
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();

        $items = $this->updateRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
    echo '<pre>';
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        print_r($item->getData());exit;
    }

    }   catch (\Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    }
}
```

**Question:** How to get all scheduled changes for a product by sku?

Comment: Are using any third party extension or what?

Comment: No. Scheduling is Magento enterprise default feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can get all existing schedules of a product by product id.

```
  <?php
    
    namespace Vendor\CustomImport\Model\Import;
    
    use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
    use Magento\Staging\Model\Entity\Upcoming\SearchResultFactory;
    
    class Test
    {
    
        protected $request;
        protected $searchResultFactory;
    
        public function __construct (
            RequestInterface $request,
            SearchResultFactory $searchResultFactory
        ) {
            $this->request = $request;
            $this->searchResultFactory = $searchResultFactory;
        }
    
        public function getSchedule($productId)
        {
        $schedules = [];
        try {
            $params = [
                'entityRequestName' => 'id',
                'entityTable' => 'catalog_product_entity',
                'entityColumn' => 'entity_id'
            ];
            $this->request->setParams( ['id' => $productId]);
            $schedules = $this->searchResultFactory->create($params);
            foreach ($schedules as $schedule) {
                echo $schedule->getName();
                echo $schedule->getStartTime();
                // Get Other values
            }
        }   catch (\Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        return  $schedules;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find related schedule product updates by searching in product entity table, filtering by created_in where equal to id from staging_update. (initially created product has created_in = 1)

So, for the sake of simplicity, in your items foreach loop, do something like this

```
$scheduledChanges = [];
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $productSearchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFieldter('created_in', $item->getId())->create();
    $products = $this->productRepository->getList($productSearchCriteria)->getItems();

    foreach($products as $product) {
        $scheduledChanges[$product->getSku()] = $scheduledChanges[$product->getSku()] ?? [];
        $scheduledChanges[$product->getSku()][] = $item->getName();
    }
}
// print_r($scheduledChanges); // the array would group scheduled updates by SKU
```

additionally, you may want to add a **is_rollback is null** filter to the staging table if you don't care about rollback updates.

Comment: It says The "created_in" attribute name is invalid. Reset the name and try again.